# Test sends with strange personalization strings

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are getting this personalization string appended to the end of our emails when we try to send test sends, but absent in the live version.

```
%%_OpenImageURL%%
```

Has anyone encountered this or is it one of the release related bugs?

Comment: I saw it too, just hid it with some CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It seems to be release related. As a workaround use send preview to generate tests or generate tests via a user-initiated send.

Also as another option you can remove the tracking image tag

`<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"></custom>`

and this string will no longer appear. However you will lose the ability to track opens for this emails sends.

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same issue.  When you look at test sends in the tracking you we also see many AMPScript functions like `%%=BeginAssetBlock(Number)=%%` `%%=EndAssetBlock()=%%` for each content block we defined and used separately in the email.